# How do I cast the value returned by a function to type ftplib.FTP_TLS?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. When I return a value from a function in another module the retuned value is always of class Function. For example:

```
# Module pdc_utils.py
def GetServerConnection():
    # Returns a connection to the FTP server.
    pdcFtp = ftplib.FTP_TLS(FTP_SERVER)
    pdcFtp.login(USER_NAME, PASSWORD)
    return pdcFtp


pdc_list_files.py
import pdc_utils

# Module pdc_test.py
def TestConn():
    pdcFtp = pdc_utils.GetServerConnection
    print('***', type(pdcFtp), '***')
```

Calling `TestConn()` produces *** Class function ***

What must I do to cast the returned value (pdcFtp) to class ftplib.FTP_TLS?

Comment: Python doesn't have "casts". Your problem here is you aren't calling the function

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are assigning the variable `pdcFtp` to the *function* `GetServerConnection` not the *result* of that function. The correct code is:

```
def TestConn():
    pdcFtp = pdc_utils.GetServerConnection()
    print('***', type(pdcFtp), '***')
```